# getEventManager in ZF2 does not work

Tags: zend-framework2

I have this code, where to get getEventManager but does not seem to work:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Service;

use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerAwareInterface;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;

class ServiceUser implements EventManagerAwareInterface
{

    protected $eventManager;

    public function insert($data)
    {
        $this->getEventManager()->trigger('user.new', $this, array('user' => $data));
    }

    public function setEventManager(EventManagerInterface $eventManager)
    {
        $eventManager->addIdentifiers(array(__CLASS__, get_called_class(), 'Module\User'));

        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEventManager()
    {
        return $this->eventManager;
    }
}
```

the error that is generated:

> Call to a member function trigger() on a non-object in

Answer (score 0):

How do you construct your `ServiceUser` object? The `*Aware` interfaces only work when you construct them via the service locator.

So, you need to register the service in your configuration:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'user-service' => 'My\Foo\Service\User',
    ),
),
```

And then request the service via the service locator (for example, in your controller):

```
$service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('user-service');
```

This will give you a service where the event manager is injected into.

Comment: the service works well, the error is when I call $this-> getEventManager()->trigger(). If I do not call $this-> getEventManager()->trigger(), Support Department works well.

Comment: The service manager has an initialiser in the root SM to inject a new event manager with configured shared manager for the aware interfaces. So if you use the right SM which is set up correctly, it should work the OTB.